# jqgrid not displaying, mvc 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

I am using asp.net MVC 3 , and my table is not displayed.
Then I had built another project, but in MVC 4. Everything worked fine.

My Controller code:

```
public JsonResult GetTodoLists(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows, Billboard billboard)  //Gets the todo Lists.
    {
        int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
        int pageSize = rows;
        var todoListsResults = db.billboard.Select(
                a => new
                {
                    a.BillboardID,
                    a.Event_date,
                    a.Event_name,

                });
        int totalRecords = todoListsResults.Count();
        var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)rows);
        if (sord.ToUpper() == "DESC")
        {
            todoListsResults = todoListsResults.OrderByDescending(s => s.Event_name);
            todoListsResults = todoListsResults.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
        }
        else
        {
            todoListsResults = todoListsResults.OrderBy(s => s.Event_name);
            todoListsResults = todoListsResults.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
        }
        var jsonData = new
        {
            total = totalPages,
            page,
            records = totalRecords,
            rows = todoListsResults
        };

        return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

My View code:

```
<h2>Todo List</h2>
<div>
<table id="grid"></table>
<div id="pager"></div>
</div>
<head>

<title>jqGrid</title>

<link href="~/Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js"></script>  
<script src="~/Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-ru.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Billboard.js"></script>


</head>
```

And my js code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

$("#grid").jqGrid({
    url: "/Home/GetTodoLists",
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'Get',
    colNames: ['BillboardID', 'Event_date', 'Event_name', ],
    colModel: [
        { key: true, hidden: true, name: 'BillboardID', index: 'BillboardID', editable: true },
        { key: false, name: 'Event_date', index: 'Event_date', width: 80, editable: true, },
        { key: false, name: 'Event_name', index: 'Event_name', editable: true, editrules: true },
        ],

    pager: jQuery('#pager'),
    rowNum: 5, 
    rowList: [5, 10, 15],
    height: '20%',

    viewrecords: true,
    caption: 'Афиша',
    emptyrecords: 'No records to display',
    jsonReader: {
        root: "rows",
        page: "page",
        total: "total",
        records: "records",
        repeatitems: false,
        Id: "0"
    },
    autowidth: true,
    multiselect: false,
}).navGrid('#pager', { edit: false, add: true, del: true, search: true, refresh: true },
    {
        // edit options
        zIndex: 100,
        url: '/Home/Edit',
        closeOnEscape: true,
        closeAfterEdit: true,
        recreateForm: true,
        afterComplete: function (response) {
            if (response.responseText) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        }
    },
    {
        // add options
        zIndex: 100,
        url: "/Home/Create",
        closeOnEscape: true,
        closeAfterAdd: true,
        afterComplete: function (response) {
            if (response.responseText) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        }
    },
    {
        // delete options
        zIndex: 100,
        url: "/Home/Delete",
        closeOnEscape: true,
        closeAfterDelete: true,
        recreateForm: true,
        msg: "Are you sure you want to delete this task?",
        afterComplete: function (response) {
            if (response.responseText) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        }
    });
    });
```

What is the problem ? Where am I wrong?

Comment: First of all you should move `<h2>Todo List</h2><div><table id="grid">/table><div id="pager"></div></div>` **out of** `<head>` and place it in the `<body>`. It's better that you open the source of the resulting HTML page and post the full code of the page. Please write always which fork of jqGrid you use ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or old jqGrid in version <=4.7) and in which version.

Comment: @Oleg , thx for information. I use JQuery.jqGrid version 4.4.4

Comment: It's really retro version of jqGrid. I would recommend you to upgrade to [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.9.2 (see many articles from [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki)). Nevertheless the code with 4.4.4 version should work too. You should post more full code which you use (full HTML page) or to post the link to the demo which uses non-minimized version of jqGrid (`jquery.jqgrid.src.js` instead of `jquery.jqgrid.min.js`). Having the demo one can reproduce the problem, see the full code, debug it and to find the reason of the problem.

Comment: @Oleg , Problem was solved. I just changed all connection strings, like this:
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js")"></script> 

thx for help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved.
Change this:

```
<link href="~/Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js"></script>  
<script src="~/Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-ru.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Billboard.js"></script>
```

on:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js")"></script> 
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Billboard.js")"></script>
```